# How I use this line from the YouTube api?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, feed

I want to use the YouTube api to make a feed of all of my uploaded videos. The YouTube API leads me to the following line:

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/0HK3ah8WCQg5KojsKfc54w/uploads`

Nevertheless, I don't know how to go from here. Inserting the line in my HTML file, which is probably a dumb thing to do in general, doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to parse the XML.